# .htaccess file makes my directory become invisible in FileZilla

Tags: apache-http-server, filezilla

I tried looking at similar questions on here, but they didn't encounter a problem similar to mine on FileZilla.

I create a `.htaccess` file and `.htpasswd`, put it into the folder with all my files, and when I go onto the public host server site with all the directories, my one becomes completely invisible. I want it to be visible, but I need it to prompt for a username and password. Here is the code I used:

`.htaccess`

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile http://domain_name_of_server/2015/student_number/name_of_directory_folder/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

`.htpasswd` layout:

```
My_username:generated_password
```

What could the problem be making it invisible? And how could it be fixed so it prompts for a password?

Comment: Once there, make sure you tell them what does it mean "in FileZilla"? FTP or SFTP protocol? Did you try another client (of the same protocol)? A log file (=real log file, not message log from GUI) can be useful too.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.htaccess` file is blowing up the directory because your `AuthUserFile` location is incorrect.  `AuthUserFile` expects a file path, not a network location: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authn_file.html

Comment: How can I locate my file path for my FTP folder?

Comment: You can specify the path relative to the htaccess file.

Comment: Yes, but how can I find the name of that path?

Comment: Hard to answer--it all depends where you created the htpasswd file.